# Удаление websocket сессии при удалении http сессии

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-websocket

Делаю приложение где можно зарегистрироваться и оставлять сообщения, но столкнулся с проблемой некорректного отображения имени созздавшего сообщение.
Насколько я понял суть проблемы в том что при logout удаляется только контекст безопасности отвечающий за http, но вот подключение websocket остается нетронутым и, если не перегружая страницу зайти в другую учетку то получится так что сообщение отправлено под другим именем.
Искал на сайсте Spring ответ по этому вопросу,но мой уровень не так высок что бы понять как использовать то что там написано.
 Может быть есть просто способ разорвать соединение websocket после выхода?

Конфигурация Websocket:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages
                .simpDestMatchers("/*").permitAll();
    }


    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/section");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addEndpoint("/forum")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        //disable CSRF for websockets for now...
        return true;
    }
}
```